# Persist data changes to account

Tags: anchor

I am passing in an `UncheckedAccount` which is an account that can be any number of different accounts, inside my instruction I then go through and figure out which account type it is by calling something like `&mut Account::<'_, Foo>::try_from(unchecked_account_info).unwrap()`

After I have the typed account, I access a field and I want to update the data in this field and have it persist after the instruction, however the update is not persisting, I check by fetching the account after the instruction completes successfully.

How can I persist the data?

I was thinking I could CPI another instruction that is typed to update the data but I was hoping I could do it all in one instruction.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, need to call `exit` on the `Account` type to persist the data and write to the underlying `AccountInfo`

Code Example:

An instruction with an UncheckedAccount, maybe this is setup because multiple different accounts can be passed in here (generic)

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FooIx<'info> {
  my_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}
```

Now, you want to assert which data type:

```
let typed = &mut Account::<'_, Bar>::try_from(&ctx.accounts.my_account)?;
```

Now access the field you want to update its data

```
typed.a_field = "updated_data";
```

Call exit() to persist this data after the instruction end, pass in the currently executing program_id

```
typed.exit(&crate::id())
```